# Obtener la hora dependiendo del timezone en PHP

Tags: php, php7, date, timezone

Estoy intentando desarrollar un sumador de minutos, en dicho Script busco obtener la hora del Cliente y no del Servidor para sumarle a esa hora la cantidad de minutos deseada y que el resultado  sea la hora del cliente segun su zona horaria ya sea de Estados Unidos, China, Holanda, entre otras en cual sea que se encuentre el Cliente mas el minuto sumado.

```
$minuto = "20"; //minuto que sera seteado
$hora="0"; //hora en cero, ya que solo se sumaran los minutos
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles"); //zona horaria seteada America/Los_Angeles
$mifecha = new DateTime(); //se obtiene la hora segun la zona horaria (4:00)
$mifecha->modify('+'.$hora.' hours'); //la hora se mantiene ya que no se le suma ningun valor
$mifecha->modify('+'.$minuto.' minute'); //se suma el valor del minuto seteado (20 minutos)
$horanueva = $mifecha->format('h:i'); //y se obtiene la hora mas el minuto agregado (4:20)
```

El codigo mostrado anteriormente intento modificarle `date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");` para que reconozca la zona horaria del Cliente, sin tener que setear una zona horaria y tambien no dejar que asigne la zona hora default que en ese caso seria la del servidor donde se encuentra alojado el Script.

Es decir, si estoy en Estados Unidos (4:00 pm) y me conecto a una VPN cuyo servicio me asgina una ubicación en Londres (9:00 pm) el resultado de `$horanueva = $mifecha->format('h:i');` deberia ser `echo $horanueva;// 9:20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias opciones para lograrlo, pero no existe una función o clase nativa de PHP que lo haga automáticamente por ti.

1. Usando librerías como GeoIP

Esta librería usa una base de datos para buscar a qué zona pertenece determinada IP y, por supuesto, funcionará como lo necesitas, con la IP del usuario, proxy o VPN, según el caso.

PHP tiene una librería de [GeoIP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.geoip.php), pero no sé si aún la siguen actualizando, la única vez que lo necesité, usé directamente la versión oficial descargable de [Maxmind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geoip2-city-country-csv-databases/)

2. Seleccionable por el usuario

Quizá esta sea la opción que menor tiempo te llevaría para adaptar, pero también la menos confiable.

3. Javascript

Es muy fácil obtener la diferencia horaria con un objeto de fecha y [.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset), ahora solo faltaría ver cómo lo envías a PHP, probablemente por AJAX o cookie.

Al final, la opción a elegir dependerá de la magnitud del proyecto y qué tan confiable necesitas que sea la información.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si, me di cuenta, programarlo para elegir la zona horaria podría ser una opción al igual que las API de GeoIP y las variables obtenidas reemplazen la zona horaria. También acabo de encontrar un ejemplo en Javascript quien si da la hora actual del equipo del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Kn4:

Quizá podrías utilizar DateTimeZone para esto.

```
$fecha_actual = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') );
echo $fecha_actual->format('H:i');
```

Salida:

```
14:42
```

Podrías pasarle como DateTimeZone el resultado de la zona que obtengas llamando a date_default_timezone_get().

Luego para obtener el timezone de un cliente según la web que visite que ejecute tu script, lamentablemente tendría que hacerse utilizando también js. Podrías mirar el siguiente enlace, podría ser de utilidad: https://usefulangle.com/post/31/detect-user-browser-timezone-name-in-php

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta. Pero busco es identificar la zona horaria del usario quien utilizaria el script, en este caso yo compile el script que used acaba de comentar y lo testee utilizando una hora diferente y el resultado que me daba era diferente. Usted esta seteando `DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') );` y si yo acceso desde otra ubicacion me seguira mostrando la zona horaria predeterminada.

Comment: Sí, lamentablemente se tendría que hacer usando otros métodos. Como indica Triby también se podría usar GeoIP. Hay librerías de GeoIP que aunque no sean de las que pagues tienen información actualizada en su mayoría. Sino, podrías utilizar javascript como también indicamos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Epero poderte ayudar:

```
$minuto = "20"; //minuto que sera seteado
$hora="0"; //hora en cero, ya que solo se sumaran los minutos
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Los_Angeles'); //zona horaria seteada America/Los_Angeles
echo date("h:i A",strtotime('+' . $minuto . 'minutes')); //se suma el valor del minuto seteado (20 minutos)
```